# Is SU(2) a subgroup of the exceptional lie group $G_2$?

Tags: lie-groups, exceptional-isomorphisms

I am not an expert in Lie groups and I have spent ages looking at textbooks; I assume that because I haven't found this statement explicitly it must either be untrue or obvious ;)

The only thing I can find is that $G_2$ definitely has a subgroup $SU(3)$*, and I know (?) that $SU(3)$ has a subgroup $SU(2)$ - surely that means the answer to my question is yes? Any help gladly appreciated!

Added: And if the answer is yes, is there an 'obvious' way to see it, possibly in terms of the octonions themselves? (This is in reference to the algebra, not the gorup - but I have noticed that any three elements of the (imaginary) octonions themselves form a Lie algebra isomorphic to $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ (since they are alternating), is this related?)

*Source http://arxiv.org/pdf/0902.0431.pdf

Comment: You switch from talking about Lie groups to talking about Lie algebras halfway through your question; which is it? If the question is about Lie groups, which form of $G_2$ are you talking about? The compact real form?

Comment: seems like http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/octonions/oct.pdf will be worth a glance.

Comment: Qiaochu Yuan - I am talking about the group - the last parenthetical statement was just me musing, and asking if it was related. As to which form - any form? Can you answer the question in general?

Comment: James - that is one of the texts I have scoured ;)

Comment: @Erik: $SU(2)$ refers to a Lie group, not a Lie algebra; the corresponding Lie algebra is called $\mathfrak{su}(2)$.

Comment: I have adjusted the LaTeX - but do you have an answer to my question?

Comment: @Erik: before that, can you clarify which Lie group called $G_2$ you're talking about? Is it the compact real form? (This is the one that's compact and has $14$ real dimensions.)

Comment: Are you able please to answer the question in general, as in for the real form, the complex form and the split-complex form?

Comment: Or if that is mistaken, tell me - as I have said, I am not an expert, any guidance you can give is appreciated.

Comment: Well thanks Qiaochu Yuan that was really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

It is a basic fact of group theory that if $H$ is a subgroup of $K$ and $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ then $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. This should be a straightforward exercise encountered right after the definition of subgroups, which is *way* before learning about Lie groups or octonions. So if $SU(2)$ is a subgroup of $SU(3)$ and $SU(3)$ is a subgroup of $G_2$, then of course $SU(2)$ is a subgroup of $G_2$.

Here, we can identify $G_2$ with the automorphism group of the octonions $\mathbb{O}$. Then $SU(3)$ is stabilizer of $i$, or equivalently the pointwise stabilizer of $\mathbb{C}$, making the orthogonal complement within $\mathbb{O}$ a copy of $\mathbb{C}^3$. And $SU(2)\cong Sp(1)$ is the pointwise stabilizer of the quaternions $\mathbb{H}$, making the orthogonal complement of $\mathbb{H}$ within $\mathbb{O}$ another copy of $\mathbb{H}$ which $Sp(1)=S^3$ acts on effectively by multiplication.

Any imaginary octonion generates a copy of $\mathbb{C}$, any two linearly independent ones generate a copy of $\mathbb{H}$, and any three "algebraically" independent imaginaries (i.e. none of the three are contained in the subalgebra contained by the other two) generate all of $\mathbb{O}$. That implies the "subalgebra" generated by *commutators* from two independent imaginaries is a copy of $\mathfrak{so}(2)$, and from three independent imaginaries is $(\mathbb{R}^7,\times)$ where $\times$ is the 7D cross product induces from octonion multiplication. This is *not* a Lie algebra; the failure of octonions to be associative implies the Jacobi identity is not satisfied.