# Maximal Closed Subgroups of $ G_2 $

Tags: reference-request, finite-groups, representation-theory, lie-groups

Consider the compact group $ G_2 $. What are the maximal closed subgroups of $ G_2 $?

Edit: the tentative list in my question kept improving to the point that I felt pretty confident in it, so I just posted it as an answer

Comment: I can confirm that $SO(4)$ is maximal and self-normalizing.  The easiest way I know to see it is to note that $G_2/SO(4)$ has the rational cohomology of $\mathbb{H}P^2$.  In particular, it has Euler characteristic $3$, which easily implies it can't be a non-trivial bundle where the fiber and base are orientable manifolds.  This implies $SO(4)$ is maximal among connected groups.  In addition, a Lefschetz argument shows any self map of $G_2/SO(4)$ has a fixed point, so it can't cover anything non-trivially.  This implies $SO(4)$ can't be the identity component of a disconnected subgroup.

Comment: @JasonDeVito https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4415293/758507  uses the action of $ G_2 $ on the octonions to describe the $ SU_3 $ subgroup as the stabilizer of the octonion $ i $ and the $ SU_2 $ subgroup as the stabilizer of the quaternion subalgebra. Do you know of any way of describing the $ SO_4 $ subgroup of $ G_2 $ as the stabilizer of some sub object of the quaternions? I'll also remove the Normalizer from the $ SO_4 $ now that you've confirmed its self-normalizing.

Comment: Yes:  $SO(4)$ is the stabilizer of the *set* of quaternions.  What I mean is that the elements of $SO(4)$ preserve the set of quaternions, though not necessarily pointwise.  So, you can see that the $SU_2$ you've already described is a subset of $SO(4)$.  The other $SU_2$ in $SO(4)$ is a little harder to describe, and is *not* conjugate to a subgroup of $SU(3)$.

Comment: Ah I see, $ SU_3 $ is the stabilizer of $ i $, equivalently the pointwise stabilizer of the complex numbers $ \mathbb{C} $.  The $ SU_2 $ subgroup of $ SU_3 $ is the intersection of the stabilizer of $ i $ and the stabilizer of $ j $ and the stabilizer of $ k $, equivalently the pointwise stabilizer of the quaternions $ \mathbb{H} $. Finally the $ SO_4 $ subgroup is the setwise stabilizer of $ \mathbb{H} $. In other words, the pointwise stabilizer of $ \mathbb{H} $ is the $ SU_2 $ subgroup $ SO_4(\mathbb{R})\cap SU_3 $ while the rest of $ SO_4(\mathbb{R})$  basically permutes around $ i,j,k $.

Comment: The group of automorphism of $\mathbb{H}$ is actually only an $SO(3)$, not an $SO(4)$.  So, $SO_4(\mathbb{R}))$ does permute around $i,j,k$, but it also maps $\ell$ to some other element of $\ell \mathbb{H}$.  This freedom accounts for the "other" $SU_2$ in $SO_4(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: The setwise stabilizer of $\Bbb H\subset\Bbb O$ acts as $SO(4)$ on $\Bbb H^\perp$ and as $SO(3)$ on ${\rm Im}\Bbb H=\Bbb R^3$ (which are algebra automorphisms of $\Bbb H$). The pointwise stabilizer is the kernel of $SO(4)\to SO(3)$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Table 2 of link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00209-019-02324-7 claims that the maximal connected subgroup of $ G_2 $
 are of type $ A_2,A_1A_1,A_1 $ 
. $ A_2 $ 
 corresponds to the $ SU(3) $
 above. $ A_1A_1 $
 corresponds to the $ SO_4 $
 above. Do you have any idea what the maximal connected $ A_1 $
 could be? Some kind of $ SU_2 $
 or $ SO_3 $
 that isn't contained in the $ SU_3 $ 
 or the $ SO_4 $? Perhaps its the $ 7 $ dimensional irrep of $ SO_3 $ thinking of $ G_2 $ as a subgroup of $ SO_7 $?

Comment: Yes, you nailed it.  The extra $A_1$ is the $7$-dim irrep of $SO(3)$.  This is apparently proved in Dynkin's "Semisemisimple subalgebras of semiseimple Lie algebras" but I haven't yet secured and English version and I don't read/speak Russian.  By the way, about 3 days ago, I happened to finish the computation of the (integral) cohomology groups of $G_2/SO(3)_{max}$ for a project I'm working on :-)

Comment: I think the group $2^3:GL(3,2)$ is actually not $AGL(3,2)$ but the non-split extension, by the way. That group embeds in $G_2(\mathbb C)$ whereas the other one does not.

Comment: @JasonDeVito That's so cool! Let me know when you post to to arXiv :) I'll show it to my friend Keith he loves extremely labor intensive calculations of cohomology groups. Also I'll check the UMD library and see if we have some english translations of Dynkin's work. Seems like he did a lot of stuff relevant to maximal subgroups/subalgebras of simple Lie groups.

Comment: If the proof goes anywhere, I will let you know.  If you do get your hands on a translation of the article, I'd be very interested.  I have a friend here who can read Russian, but the paper is so long and I'm not sure where the result is in the paper...

Comment: @DavidA.Craven That is very interesting to me. So $ 2^3:GL(3,2) $ is GAP $ PerfectGroup(1344,2) $ rather than $ AGL(3,2)=PerfectGroup(1344,1) $. Do you know anything about $ G_2(2) $ the almost simple group of order 12096? Does $ G_2(2) $ contain the nonsplit $ 2^3:GL(3,2) = PerfectGroup(1344,2) $? Does $ G_2(2) $ contain $ SL(2,8) $? Also I'm curious how you know $ AGL(3,2) $ doesn't embed in $ G_2(\mathbb{C}) $ while nonsplit $ 2^3:GL(3,2) = PerfectGroup(1344,2) $ does embed?

Comment: @JasonDeVito You had a wonderful argument for why the $ SO_4 $ subgroup is self-normalizing. Do you think the $ SO(3)_{max} $ subgroup is also self-normalizing? (Jeff Adams shared a dropbox folder with me yesterday that has some ATLAS results showing it is indeed self normalizing, but I always enjoy your algebraic topology proofs!)

Comment: @Ian:  No, I was not aware of this result.  The homogeneous space $G_2/SO(3)_{max}$ is a rational sphere of dimension $11$, so there is no immediate reason why it can't cover lots of things.  E.g., $S^{11}$ admits a free action by any finite subgroup of $Sp(1)$.

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira All maximal subgroups of $G_2(F)$ are known for all fields $F$, as it's a very small group. There is a single class of $2^3$ subgroups, and this has the non-split normalizer. $G_2(2)=PSU_3(3).2$ has a $6$-dimensional representation, whereas any group $2^3.GL(3,2)$ has only representations of degrees 7 and above, so cannot embed. Same with $SL_2(8)$.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Oh I see. If they are known for all $ F $ would you be able to post a list of the maximal subgroups of $ G_2(\mathbb{C}) $ as an answer? I would accept that since that would basically be equivalent to the maximal subgroups of compact $ G_2 $. If not I think I might just post an answer because now that Jason has weighed in on the positive dimensional subgroups and you have weighed in on the finite subgroups I'm feeling pretty confident about my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full list is
Maximal Subgroups of Type I (normalizer of a maximal connected subgroup):
\begin{align*}
& SU(3):2  \\
& SO(4) \\
& SO(3)_{max} \\
\end{align*}

Maximal Subgroups of Type II (finite maximal closed subgroup):
\begin{align*}
& SL(2,8) \;\text{simple}\\
&PSL(2,13) \;\text{simple}
 \\
& 2^3\cdot SL(3,2) \;\text{normalizer of an elementary abelian $ p $ group}\\
&G_2(2) \;\text{almost simple}
\end{align*}

For what it's worth, $ G_2/SO(4) $ is one of the compact irreducible symmetric spaces it has euler chracteristic $ 3 $.
Also $ G_2/SU(3)=S^6$ and $ G_2/(SU(3):2)=\mathbb{R}P^6 $.

For the positive dimensional subgroup of $ G_2 $ I'm using prop 2.3 of

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00209-019-02324-7

For the finite subgroups of $ G_2 $ I'm using this reference

https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01884298.pdf

1.4 corollary 2. which says that the only finite subgroups not contained in a proper positive dimensional subgroup of $ G_2 $ are

\begin{align*}
& SL(3,2)\\
& SL(3,2):2\cong Aut(SL(3,2))\\
& 2^3 \cdot SL(3,2)=PerfectGroup(1344,2)\\
& G_2(2)'\cong PSU(3,3) \\
& G_2(2)\cong Aut(PSU(3,3)) \\
& SL(2,8) \\
& PSL(2,13) \\
\end{align*}

Note: it easy to get character table for almost simple group $ AutomorphismGroup(PSU(3,3)) $ in GAP.

$ G_2(2) $ contains $ G_2(2)' $ and $ SL(3,2) $ as a subgroup.

$ SL(3,2)\cdot 2\cong Aut(SL(3,2)) $ is not maximal since it is a subgroup of $ SU(3):2 $.

($ SU(3) $ has a $ SL(3,2) $ subgroup. A nontrivial element of the normalizer acts as an outer automorphism of $ SU_3 $, essentially complex conjugation, and that descends to an outer automorphism of the $ SL(3,2) $ subgroup. That is how we get $ SL(3,2)\cdot 2 $ as a subgroup of $ SU_3\cdot 2 $).

So the maximal finite subgroups are
$$  
SL(2,8), PSL(2,13), 2^3\cdot GL(3,2), G_2(2) 
$$
of sizes $ 504,1092,1344,12096 $ respectively.

Divisibility rules out all inclusions except for possibly $ SL(2,8) $ in $ G_2(2) $ and $ 2^3\cdot GL(3,2) $ in $ G_2(2) $. There cannot be an $ SL(2,8) $ subgroup of $ G_2(2) $ because $ G_2(2) $ has a 6d irrep while the first non trivial rep of $ SL(2,8) $ has degree 7. And there cannot be a $ 2^3:SL(3,2) $ subgroup of $ G_2(2) $ because the first faithful rep of $ 2^3\cdot SL(3,2) $ has degree 7. (there are 6d reps just not faithful, either the 6d non faithful irrep or direct sum of 3d irreps but all 3d irreps have same kernel so no direct sum can be faithful).

$ PSL(2,13),2^3\cdot SL(3,2), G_2(2)  $ have 14d real irreps. So another way to show these are maximal is that the adjoint action coincides with the 14d irrep and they are maximal finite, so maximal finite + Ad-irreducible implies maximal closed.

For $ SL(2,8) $ no similarly direct proof exists and we just have to use the fact that the first irrep of $ SL(2,8) $ is degree 7 to rule out $ SL(2,8) $ being a a subgroup of $ SU_3,SO_4 $,and also observe that $ SL(2,8) $ is not contained in $ PSL(2,13) $ by divisibility. And again not contained in $ G_2(2) $ because all reps of degree $ <7 $ are trivial.

[Edit: $ N(T) $ used to be on the list I took it off because it's actually in $ SU(3).2 $]
Note that $ N(T)=(U_1 \times U_1) : D_6 $ the normalizer of the rank 2 maximal torus (the Weyl group $ N(T)/T\cong D_6 $ is the twelve element dihedral group) is contained in $ N(SU(3))=SU(3):2 $, the normalizer of the well known $ SU_3 $ subgroup of $ G_2 $ (famously $ G_2/SU(3) $ is the 6-sphere $ S^6 $).

[EDIT: Jason DeVito has confirmed $ SO(4) $ is self normalizing and maximal]. I don't know much about the $ SO(4) $ subgroup of $ G_2 $ but I'm pretty sure it exists and is self-normalizing.

[EDIT: David A. Craven has pointed out that $ 2^3\cdot SL(3,2) $ is actually not the $ ASL(3,2)=PerfectGroup(1344,1) $ subgroup of the $ A_8 $ subgroup of $ SO(7) $ but rather the nonsplit extension with GAP ID $ PerfectGroup(1344,2) $]